# NullPointerException when calling findViewById in onCreate

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-view, findviewbyid

Whenever I use findViewById in my Activity's onCreate I get a NullPointerException. For example:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
    TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
}
```

I have read that the problem might by that the views may not be fully loaded when I try to find them and that is why I get a null pointer. If I call for findViewById in onCreateView of my Activity's fragment, everything works fine:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
            false);
    TextView mTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
}
```

However, I need to use mTextView outside this fragment class. I have seen many examples in Android's official documentation where findViewById is used in the Activity's onCreate. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You was not supose to use setContentView on Fragment, and not manipulate layout at onCreate http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Where should I manipulate layout then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the layout xmls, place your `textview` in the layout xml- `activity_main` so the activity's `setContentView` can find it there.

Currently the `textview` is in the layout xml `fragment_main`

fyi: `fragment_main` and `activity_main` are two different layouts. If your app structure doesn't demand the fragment then you don't need it at all.

Comment: That is what I was missing. Thank you a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this -

```
class MainActivity extends Activity{
public TextView tv;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
......
}
public void doActionOnTextView()
{
   //at this point you have the textview in tv
   // do what you want to do with it
}
}
class MyFragment extends Fragment{

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
        false);
TextView mTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
mTextView.postRunnable(new Runnable(){
((MainActivity)getActivity()).tv=mTextView;
((MainActivity)getActivity()).doActionOnTextView();

}
}
```

Its not the best solution, but would work for you now.